# Ionic cordova build android return failed

Tags: ionic-framework

when I run ionic cordova build android --prod --release on my cli it shows this error.

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ‘:processReleaseResources’.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --release (exit
code 1).
```

I tried many solutions and they didn't work, can someone please help.

Comment: can you try `cordova build android --release --verbose`?

Comment: did you change anything in **build.gradle** file

Comment: Please post all the error message for easy understanding.

Comment: No id didnt , This are the only error i get .

Comment: @SurajRao what will happen if i run the command ? does it effect my whole project ?

Comment: no.. it will build a release apk and show logs in verbose